# Wording of third-party login button

Tags: terminology, login, signup-signon

Which one do you think is the right way to put it: "Sign up with Google"
or "Sign up using Google"?

I feel that "Sign up using Google" is the right way to ask, as "Sign up with Google" says that you are actually signing up with Google and not with the particular product. But a few guys on my team said that both phrases are the same.

Please give me a suggestion on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I don't think there is a definitive way to do it.**

Often times there isn't even a text label associated with the alternative login option.

For example logging in to Stack Exchange presents you with this login screen:
[image]

Soundcloud presents you with this login screen:
[image]

You don't have to have a label for your Google login. If, however, you needed to choose between *with* and *using*, I would go with using, as that seems to be the terminology I've seen most, but I have no real supporting evidence towards if that is the "definitive" way of doing it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply..This question has been bothering me a lot and good that i brought it to this forum to get clarity on this. Thanks for the help. I am planning to go with using.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with the guys on your team, the phrases have the same meaning.

> [**with**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/with) (preposition) - indicating the instrument used to perform an action. *"cut the fish with a knife"*
>
> [**use**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/use) (verb) take, hold, or deploy (something) as a means of accomplishing or achieving something; employ. *"she used her key to open the front door"*-

However, Google recommends both ["Sign in with Google"](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines#text) and ["Sign up with Google"](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines#text).

Comment: I agree. Sign in with google makes total sense. But Signup with google doesn't equate. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: @RamnanArumugam I updated my answer. I left out Google's recommendation for sign up by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

i think both depicts the same meaning with a slight bit of difference in their tone, as we daily use the term "With" for many tasks like, imagine for example : "*boy, eat it with spoon......hey, pull out the thread with your finger."*

Here if i say, *"hey, pull out the thread using your finger"*. Surely, the first one having "WITH" is a more direct way assuming the user with a hold of common sense, that the user will just use it **(here focus is not specific on "finger")**. On the other hand **"USING"** term tries to provide the focus majorly on the thing  ***( "finger" )*** that you need to use.